# Shouldn't this question be marked as off topic?

Tags: discussion, closing-questions, close-reasons, vote-to-close

The question [Why does Wrestling and BJJ exist when Sambo and catch-wrestling are more complete arts?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/9786/why-does-wrestling-and-bjj-exist-when-sambo-and-catch-wrestling-are-more-complet) is off topic and needs to be closed.

### Opinion based

The question compares multiple arts and talks about which is more effective. Not only is this opinion based, but it is marked as off topic in the help center.

### Sparks debate

Since the author of the question states his controversial opinion, this is very likely to (and already has started to) start arguments in the comments about whether martial art A, B, or C is better.

Please use your ability to close questions (if you have it), because this one is undeniably off-topic. If someone would like to defend it, however, I may just change my mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I disagree this question is off-topic. Although written in a needlessly provocative tone, the core of the question is about how wrestling and BJJ are different from sambo and catch-wrestling.

I imagine a good answer for this question looks something like: because wrestling (or BJJ) has such and such rules and studies these particular situations in greater depth. This would be fact-based and verifiable.

Or you could write an answer that disputes the premise that "The number 1 reason for why people practice martial arts is self-defense" and provide data that says so.